# SQL special group in Teradata

Tags: sql, teradata

I have this data in a table:

```
service | vat | ini_date | end_date
  1        A   10/01/2017 31/01/2017
  2        A   15/01/2017 28/02/2017
  3        A   15/02/2017 31/03/2017
  4        B   15/01/2017 31/03/2017
  5        B   15/02/2017 31/03/2017
  6        B   20/04/2017 31/05/2017
  7        B   20/05/2017 31/05/2017
```

And I have to group by VAT services which have match in time.

My output should by this:

```
group service | vat | ini_date | end_date
  1    1        A   10/01/2017 31/01/2017
  1    2        A   15/01/2017 28/02/2017
  1    3        A   15/02/2017 31/03/2017
  1    4        B   15/01/2017 31/03/2017
  1    5        B   15/02/2017 31/03/2017
  2    6        B   20/04/2017 31/05/2017
  2    7        B   20/05/2017 31/05/2017
```

I can't use procedures, I'm trying with some analytical function but there is a lot of casuistics. The problem starts when you have more than three services that coincide in time individually.

Any idea is welcome.
Thanks

Comment: What's the logic to differenciate `Group 1` from `Group 2`?

Comment: It's a sequence. It has to be restarted when service in same VAT don't match in time.

Comment: Do you want to find gaps where the previous `end_date` is greater than the current `ini_date`, i.e. group all overlapping periods?

Comment: You need to be much more explicit about the logic that needs to be implemented.  Explain exactly when the `group` should change, exactly when it should not change, covering off every corner case that is relevant.  At present people are having to guess what it is you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you incrementing for each "block" of time, so one has to detect a "gap" in the dates. Below I have used a Postgres fiddle using window functions `LEAD()` to discover if there is a gap which is then arranged into the final output using `DENSE_RANK()`. In the second `cte` "common_dates" a correlated subquery is used to locate a date when the next gap has been detected. This information is then used to order the final `DENSE_RANK()`. *There may be a more efficient method in Teradata to execute this subquery but I'm not able to trial that).*

**NB:** I have assumed "service" can be used for ordering in the `LEAD()` function and in the correlated subquery.

Notes: "group" isn't something I would recommend as a column name so I used "group_num" instead  and I extended the sample data for testing the query against.

[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/4b5fc/1) (PostgreSQL 9.6)

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
    ("service" int, "vat" varchar(1), "ini_date" date, "end_date" date)
;

INSERT INTO Table1
    ("service", "vat", "ini_date", "end_date")
VALUES
    (11, 'A', '2016-01-10 00:00:00', '2016-01-31 00:00:00'),
    (21, 'A', '2016-01-15 00:00:00', '2016-02-28 00:00:00'),
    (31, 'A', '2016-02-15 00:00:00', '2016-03-31 00:00:00'),
    (41, 'B', '2016-01-15 00:00:00', '2016-03-31 00:00:00'),
    (51, 'B', '2016-02-15 00:00:00', '2016-03-31 00:00:00'),
    (61, 'B', '2016-04-20 00:00:00', '2016-05-31 00:00:00'),
    (71, 'B', '2016-05-20 00:00:00', '2016-05-31 00:00:00'),

    (91, 'A', '2017-01-10 00:00:00', '2017-01-31 00:00:00'),
    (92, 'A', '2017-01-15 00:00:00', '2017-02-28 00:00:00'),
    (93, 'A', '2017-02-15 00:00:00', '2017-03-31 00:00:00'),
    (94, 'B', '2017-01-15 00:00:00', '2017-03-31 00:00:00'),
    (95, 'B', '2017-02-15 00:00:00', '2017-03-31 00:00:00'),
    (96, 'B', '2017-04-20 00:00:00', '2017-05-31 00:00:00'),
    (97, 'B', '2017-05-20 00:00:00', '2017-05-31 00:00:00')
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
with gapflag as (
      SELECT
        *
      , lag(end_date) over(order by service) - ini_date dfdts
      , max(end_date) over() max_date
      FROM Table1
      )  
, common_dates as (     
      select
        *
        , coalesce(
                (select ini_date 
                 from gapflag t2 
                 where t2.dfdts < 1  and t2.service > gapflag.service
                 order by service limit 1)
              , 
                max_date
            ) grp_date
      from gapflag
   )
select
       dense_rank() over(order by grp_date) group_num
     , service, vat, ini_date, end_date
from common_dates
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/4b5fc/1/0)**:

```
| group_num | service | vat |   ini_date |   end_date |
|-----------|---------|-----|------------|------------|
|         1 |      11 |   A | 2016-01-10 | 2016-01-31 |
|         1 |      21 |   A | 2016-01-15 | 2016-02-28 |
|         1 |      31 |   A | 2016-02-15 | 2016-03-31 |
|         1 |      41 |   B | 2016-01-15 | 2016-03-31 |
|         1 |      51 |   B | 2016-02-15 | 2016-03-31 |
|         2 |      61 |   B | 2016-04-20 | 2016-05-31 |
|         2 |      71 |   B | 2016-05-20 | 2016-05-31 |
|         3 |      91 |   A | 2017-01-10 | 2017-01-31 |
|         3 |      92 |   A | 2017-01-15 | 2017-02-28 |
|         3 |      93 |   A | 2017-02-15 | 2017-03-31 |
|         3 |      94 |   B | 2017-01-15 | 2017-03-31 |
|         3 |      95 |   B | 2017-02-15 | 2017-03-31 |
|         4 |      96 |   B | 2017-04-20 | 2017-05-31 |
|         4 |      97 |   B | 2017-05-20 | 2017-05-31 |
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks you want to group services that overlap in time into groups.  Since Since Services 1-5 all overlap (like a chain), they become "Group 1".  Since the next service (Service 6) doesn't overlap with the previous group, you give it the next id - "Group 2" and continue.  Is that correct?

If so...a couple functions that can help you out:

Window functions (to peek at the previous row)
PERIOD data type + related functions to test for overlap